# How do I create a counter for each element in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, iteration, element

So I have to write a program that reads an arbitrary number of integers that are in the range 0 to 50 inclusive and counts how many occurrences of each are entered.  Indicate the end of the input by a value outside of the range. After  all input  has  been  processed.,  print all of the values (with  the number  of occurrences)  that were entered  one or more time.

```
public class problem
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int userInput = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int index = -1;

        for (int num = 0; num <= userInput ; num++)
        {   
            System.out.println("Please enter a random number between 0 and 50, enter a negative number to end input: ");
            num--;

            if(userInput >= 0 || userInput <= 50)
            {       
                userInput++;
                userInput = scan.nextInt();
                index++;
                myList.add(userInput);
            }
            if (userInput < 0 || userInput > 50)
            {
                myList.remove(index);
                index--;
                break;
            }
        }   

        for (int num: myList)
            System.out.print(num + " ");

    }
}
```

This is what I have so far, but I am stuck as to how to count each integer occurrence in myList.

Comment: I'm gonna first ask why you have `num--;` inside the for loop. Next, probably the only way I can think instantly is using nested for loops to loop through the list 50 times, and each pass through count the occurrences and print after each list pass through. 

However, this isn't the most efficient way to do this... so I'm sure someone else will answer with something more time efficient than O(n^2)

Comment: Hints: Take an int array `int []arr` and for each input make `arr[userInput]++`, after end of input print the number in each index of `arr` using for loop. Good Luck.

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman so should I get rid of myList?

Comment: @Colin, I added the num-- in the for loop since it was the only way for me to be able to input 0 without ending the input. And thank you for your input Colin, it may not be the most efficient, but it could be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do something like this

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 200; // this is just for test
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0;i < max; i++){
            int value = (int) (Math.random() * 50); // generate random numbers
            if(counter.containsKey(value)){ // if map contains value, increment it's count
                counter.put(value, counter.get(value)+1);
            }else{
                counter.put(value, 1); //put it and start from 1
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);

    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't learned HashMap yet so I won't be able to use it in my program, but I'll see what I can do. thanks

Comment: Okay but I would suggest you look into different data structures so you can learn ahead @studentS